# Related list property - quote showing blank window

Tags: opportunity, related-list

In Opportunity "Related list property - quote showing blank

attached image for your reference.

window"[image]

Comment: Check FLS has given to respective Quote fields

Comment: I have this exact issue, did you find what was causing this?

Comment: Experiencing this and it's post spring release.

Comment: We had something similar with rich text fields not displaying most of their buttons. This was easily fixed by removing the browser cache (chrome).

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue yesterday and got in touch with Salesforce support about this. This was only happening in my sandboxes which had been put on to the preview for Spring'17. They are looking into a patch to fix this once the Spring'17 release goes out.

The fix for this in the meantime is to:

1. Edit the page layout
2. Remove the related list
3. Save the page layout (you can't just do Quick Save within the edit window)
4. Edit the page layout
5. Re-add the related list again
6. Now when you click the properties cog, everything should display correctly

This fixed the issue for me I hope this works for you.